# ValueError: Key font.fantasy: Attempted relative import in non-package in Mercurial

Tags: python, python-3.x, mercurial

I am using mercurial and it worked fine on my computer for a long time. However when I used it today I got the following error message:

hg

```
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.0.2)
** Extensions loaded: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 45, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 60, in run
    sys.exit((dispatch(request(sys.argv[1:])) or 0) & 255)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 126, in dispatch
    ret = _runcatch(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 216, in _runcatch
    return callcatch(ui, _runcatchfunc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 225, in callcatch
    return func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 158, in _runcatchfunc
    'pdb' : pdb.set_trace
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 152, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 100, in _load
    mod = _hgextimport(_import, head, globals, locals, None, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 53, in _hgextimport
    return importfunc(name, globals, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/bin/pdb.py", line 6, in <module>
    exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
  File "/home/student/Documents/ven_python3/basekit/scripts/pdb.py", line 5, in <module>
    from basekit.utils.tool import parse_subargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 260, in _demandimport
    mod = _hgextimport(_origimport, name, globals, locals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 53, in _hgextimport
    return importfunc(name, globals, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/student/repos/basekit/basekit/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    matplotlib.use( "Agg" )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 152, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 100, in _load
    mod = _hgextimport(_import, head, globals, locals, None, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 53, in _hgextimport
    return importfunc(name, globals, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1170, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1013, in rc_params
    return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1146, in rc_params_from_file
    if key not in _all_deprecated])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 897, in __init__
    self[k] = v
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 916, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError("Key %s: %s" % (key, str(ve)))
ValueError: Key font.fantasy: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I am not sure how I caused this error, I installed mercurial in some virtualenviroments where python was not python2.7 but python3.5. Could that be the reason for this error?
However, I than removed mercurial from my system and installed it again. Strange thing is if I do the install via pip I get the above error messages. If I use apt-get install I get the message:

`abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in [/usr/bin`

So, my question is now: How do I get mercurial working again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the backtrace, you will see it fails in `matplotlib`, which seemed very strange to me: why mercurial would need matplotlib?

Googling for "mercurial matplotlib" I found various posts with problems similar to yours. It turns out that matplotlib is a dependency of the [activity extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ActivityExtension).

So I think that a workaround would be to disable that extension in your mercurial configuration file (`hg config --edit` will open the configuration file in the default editor). Then look for the line beginning with `activity=` and comment it out.

If you really need that extension, since it is not distributed with mercurial, it might be that you just need to update the source to a more recent version (the configuration file will point to the directory containing a clone of the repo of the extension, you then have to `hg pull -u` inside that directory), or you can google more about "mercurial activity" and see what is the status.

Note that the above comment about Mercurial not supporting Python 3 is misleading, since the output you pasted shows that it is using Python 2.7.

EDIT

Editing the configuration file with `hg config --edit` will fail, since the error is triggered in the configuration file itself.

You can edit the configuration file directly. Looking from the output you pasted, you are on a Unix system, so the user configuration file will be `$HOME/.hgrc`.

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for your time and afford but sadly your solutions aren't working, if I try one of these commands I get the same mistake as above, so I can't get rid of this dependency.

Comment: Happy it worked. Please consider accepting my answer then.